# How to pass a value from a java class to java frame?

Tags: java, class

I want to know How to pass a variable value from a java class (without frame) to a java frame?

I have a java class and I want to send a value from this class to a java frame.

Comment: Is this a swing project?

Comment: Have you already worked through the basic Java tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ?

Comment: The normal way you would any two classes. A `Frame` is just an instance of a `Frame` class.

Comment: What makes you think it's any different from [Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html) for any other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean:
You have a visual frame. And you have an instance of a class with data, methods, etc...
You want to show something from that class in that frame? So add it as any simple text (https://www.guru99.com/java-swing-gui.html) you just need to instantiate the class in your Main Window.

```
//This is your class
class Foo {

    private String bar;

    public Foo(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return this.bar;
    }
}

//This is your Frame
class gui {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("My First GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        Foo foo = new Foo("HELLO WORLD");
        JLabel labelBar = new JLabel(foo.getBar());
        frame.getContentPane().add(labelBar);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to submit a value?

Comment: You create a getter method that returns the value you need to use from your class into your frame, in the example is the getFoo(). If you need to get the value from your frame (ex. a TextBox) into your class you need to learn how to use events like a button click, or a key action.